# Возможно ли при помощи инструментов эмулирующих отображение на различных устройствах создать работающие приложение?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, sass, мобильные-приложения

После того, как я узнал, что в chrome и firefox есть "эмуляторы различных устройств" мне стало интересно, возможно ли при помощи их создать работающие "не криво" приложение?

Но это не все... У меня есть ещё один и главный вопрос - создавали ли конкретно Вы такое приложение? Не мифы, не ссылки на какие-то фразы меня интересуют, а реальные факты. Просто я сегодня попытался это сделать и сразу "неприятность" с отображением в chrome. В FF нормально, а в chrome не работает `background-position: top`. И как это понимать я не знаю, то ли у хрома багнутый эмулятор, а то ли у лисы.. А возможно есть и другие баги, которые существуют, но в эмуляторе их не увидишь.

up, а то всего пять просмотров, есть шанс что кто-то не заметит вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я могу предложить посмотреть в сторону метатэга viewport - возможно все баги кроются в нём. Там есть такая штука, что на разных девайсах выставляется разное масштабирование и в итоге всё плывёт на мобильнике, причём ff по умолчанию в окне адаптивной вёрстке походу просто показывает с нужным разрешением, а хром при адаптивной вёрстке масштабирует под конкретный девайс, как бы он его отобразил на самом деле. Ну а уж по кросбраузерной вёрстке - совсем другой вопрос и с мобильными девайсами не связанный.